# Need some help to improve a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I lack experience with regex and I need some help.
I need to extract a git tag. The input string is like this:

```
6dde3d91f23bff5ab81e91838f19f306b33fe7a8refs/tags/3.4.2

// there is a new line at the end of the string
```

The part of the string I need is `3.4.2`. Here is my code:

```
var pattern = /.*([0-9]{1}\.{1}[0-9]{1}\.{1}[0-9]{1}).*/ig;
var match = pattern.exec(string);
// match[1] gets what I need
```

It works, but this regex is ridiculously long, there must be a way to make it shorter. Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on the pattern you need to match? Or else a simple split would be just fine.

Comment: I still think that `/[0-9.]+$/` is the best pattern, because it also accounts for `1.0` and `1.0.100`, for instance.

Comment: @RobW in this case it could be /\d+(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?$/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `[0-9]{1}` with `\d` as follows:

```
/\d\.\d\.\d$/
```

The `$` matches the end of the line.

Edit: updated based on [Rob-W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w)'s feedback

Comment: `.*` is not needed in the expression. Also remove the parentheses, and access the result through `match[0]`.

Comment: Thanks to you both, it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

No regex is needed, just split the string.

```
var tag ="6dde3d91f23bff5ab81e91838f19f306b33fe7a8refs/tags/3.4.2";​​​​​
console.log(tag.split('/')[2]);​ // results in 3.4.2
```

Comment: This would be great but I want to be sure the match I get respect the pattern I am looking for. With this I just get the last part, it could be anything

Answer (score 0):

The `{1}` is implicit in every statement. Taking those out will shorten your expression.

[j08691's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923682/90322) is the right thing, though: just string split it.

Answer (score 0):

i got your result with `\d\..*`

can't get any shorter than this.

test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5Cd%5C..%2a&input=6dde3d91f23bff5ab81e91838f19f306b33fe7a8refs/tags/3.4.2%0A)

Comment: @NullUserException♦: nope. there is a [standard for tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Comment: Fair enough; although I don't see any "standard" format on that page.

Answer (score 0):

This is Shortest one >>

**[0-9.]+$**